# junit annotation

Tags: junit4

I wish to launch the GUI application 2 times from Java test. How should we use `@annotation` in this case?

```
public class Toto { 

    @BeforeClass 
    public static void setupOnce() { 
        final Thread thread = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
               //launch appli
            }
        }; 
        try { 
            thread.start(); 
        } catch (Exception ex) { } 
    }
}
```

```
public class Test extends toto {
    @Test 
    public void test() {
        setuptonce(); 
        closeAppli(); 
    } 

    @test 
    public void test2() 
    {
        setuptonce(); 
    } 
}
```

To launch it a second time, which annotation should I use? `@afterclass`?

Answer (score 22):

Method annotated with `@BeforeClass` means that it is run once before any of the test methods are run in the test class. Method annotated with `@Before` is run once before every test method in the class. The counterparts for these are `@AfterClass` and `@After`.

Probably you are aiming for something like the following.

```
@BeforeClass
public static void setUpClass() {
  // Initialize stuff once for ALL tests (run once)
}

@Before
public void setUp() {
  // Initialize stuff before every test (this is run twice in this example)
}

@Test
public void test1() { /* Do assertions etc. */ }

@Test
public void test2() { /* Do assertions etc. */ }

@AfterClass
public static void tearDownClass() {
  // Do something after ALL tests have been run (run once)
}

@After
public void tearDown() {
  // Do something after each test (run twice in this example)
}
```

You don't need to explicitly call the `@BeforeClass` method in your test methods, JUnit does that for you.

Comment: I have one function toto.java where I define @BeforeClass with setuponce()
another java test where I : 
-call setuponce()
- @test //test1 ,close appli
-@test2 //test2  ,re-call setup once and close ressource 
but test2 isn't done...

Comment: Would it be possible for you to add your test source code fully into your original post? I am having trouble understanding the problem.

Comment: this is Toto.java :
public class Toto {
 @BeforeClass
       public static void setupOnce() {
       final Thread thread = new Thread() {
       public void run() {
        
            //launch appli
        }
       
       };
       
       try {
          thread.start();
         
       } catch (Exception ex) {
           }  
}
}
this is Test.java : 
public class Test extends toto {
 

@Test
 public void test() {
 setuptonce();
closeAppli();
}
@test
 public void test2() {
 setuptonce(); 
}
}

Comment: I upgraded my answer with a bit of information. If you have two tests and you want to initialize something before each of them, then you should use @Before public void setUp() { ... }, if you want to initialize something only once before all the tests use @BeforeClass public static void setUpClass() { ... }.

Comment: ponzo thanks for your answer
so setuponce launch the appli only once ?
I have used the @Before and @After but when I run the test =>problem off initialization??

Comment: the @BeforeClass in my case is in another java file 
in the java test I call :
@before
@test
@test
@after

Comment: Do you need to close the tested application between tests?

Comment: yes for the first test I need to launch and close appli for the second one two

Comment: Aah ok, then you definitely need to use @Before and @After instead of @BeforeClass and @AfterClass. @Before is run before every test and @After after every test. If you're running into problems in the second test it is probably because you were not able to close the application properly in the @After method. How are you trying to close it before restarting?

Comment: by clicking on File menu->Exit 
when I try to relaunch it a second time sometimes works but open appli in the last state (not clean)

Comment: This is not really automated testing if you need user action to close the application. What are you trying to do here?

Answer (score 0):

The @BeforeClass annotation is used to run something once, before test actually runs.

So, depending on what do you want to get (and why), you can simply wrap launch code in a cycle, move launch code in other method and call it from somewhere else or write separate test case.

Comment: so when I call setuponce() ,it launch the GUI once?
how could I relaunch the GUI after closing it ? 
@test
launch GUI
close GUI
launch GUI

Comment: I don't know now do you launch gui, but, if it does not forks, you can write something like this:
public void run() {
 for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  // launch gui
 }
}

if it forks (i.e. returns control to run() from gui before it closes), then here should be some other stuff

Comment: I have one function toto.java where I define @BeforeClass with setuponce() another java test where I : -call setuponce() - @test //test1 ,close appli -@test2 //test2 ,re-call setup once and close ressource but test2 isn't done... –